# Escaping dollar sign in XML/XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, escaping

I'm handling a requirement to transform a XML (from a legacy system), using XSLT. I ran into problems dealing with tags that have the dollar sign (that's how they are stored and generated in the legacy system). Example of a sample XML file:

```
<root>
     <example>
        <problem$tag>12354</problem$tag>                
    </example>
    <thisTagIsOK>sunny day</thisTagIsOK>
</root>
```

This is my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="example">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="problem$tag>"/>
        print stuff
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried escaping the dollar with \ and with $
Both without luck.

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure $ is xml-DTD autorized ... You can remove the char '$' before xslt processing ?

Comment: It's a process that's still in development, so there's still chance. I'm still looking for a solution. If I find a definition that clearly states that it's illegal to use $ in a tag, that's my solution. Thanks!

Comment: Like Steve in his point 2, i suggested remove char preprocessing xslt. Not at the generation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to parse that as it is with XSLT because the XML spec forbids the use of the `$` symbol (as well as many others) within an element name. From the [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#NT-Name):

> The ASCII symbols and punctuation marks, along with a fairly large
>   group of Unicode symbol characters, are excluded from names because
>   they are more useful as delimiters in contexts where XML names are
>   used outside XML documents

I'd say your options are to either:

1. Modify the source system, if possible, to generate compliant XML
2. Run the XML through something to preprocess your XML to make it compliant, for example replacing the `$` symbol with an `_` (which is permitted)

Comment: Thanks. If it's illegal, that's enough for this scenario.