# How to escape $ in a XML string when using XMLTextReader in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-core

I have a xml message like

```
<hello$1>hello</hello$1>
```

, where the tag names contain $ in them, XMLTextReader throws the following exception

```
{"The '$' character, hexadecimal value 0x24, cannot be included in a name. Line 1, position 12."}
```

Is there a way to escape $ while reading the XML content, as the source content cannot be modified.

Comment: From [XML Validator](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator), this is not a valid XML.

Comment: XML has a strictly defined syntax and a document not adhering to it is simply not XML. Instead of trying to tweak the document by text manipulations (which might work for specific cases but then fail on other cases), you should really insist to get valid XML in the first place.

Comment: Why does this element have to include what looks like *data* in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping dollar sign in XML/XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607839/escaping-dollar-sign-in-xml-xslt)

Comment: If you need such data in XML, then you have defined your XML the wrong way. It can't contain that content. Model it as `<something name="hello$1">hello</something>"

Answer (score 1):

Some libraries, I believe, use the convention of replacing a disallowed character such as $ with its hex code: `_x24_`. The following would be well-formed XML:

```
<hello_x24_1>hello</hello_x24_1>
```

But a more common solution is to use a generic element name with an attribute:

```
<greeting name="hello$1">hello</greeting>
```

(Incidentally, the rule against having `$` in an element name is nothing to do with C# XmlTextReader, it's a basic rule of XML.)

Comment: Well, you can't distinguish `<hello$1>hello$1</hello$1>` from `<hello_x24_1>hello_x24_1</hello_x24_1>` then

Comment: The .NET method [`XmlConvert.EncodeName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodename?view=net-7.0) uses 4-digit escape sequences `_xHHHH_` rather than two, so `$` would become `_x0024_`.  The docs indicate that *No shortforms are allowed.*